# Existing master server software?

Tags: server

Considering there are many games out there that use some sort of a server that contains a list of current games/servers, is there an existing library I can use instead of writing my own master server?

I only wish to store game/server data (server name/ip, num players, game-specific data...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [GameSpy](http://www.poweredbygamespy.com/). According to their marketing you also gain access to (above and beyond lobbies):

- User generated content.
- Screenshots.
- Competitive leaderboards.
- Data mining.
- Matchmaking.
- Live replay streaming.

As far as I know SteamWorks also provides lobby services - but your game needs SteamWorks approval before you gain access. You could also roll your own using Azure (e.g. using AppHarbor - for free); given how simple your requirements are.

Comment: cool, I didn't know there are actual services like this on the net :)